# react-router v6 wrapped route component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can you render a composed `Route` component

[code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-v6-sample-m51eqb?file=index.js)

Bottomline from above example is that in the following code, the `Wrapped` route will never render it's element

```
const App = () => (
      <Routes>
        <Wrapped/>
        <Route path="/inline" element={<span >Inline works</span>} />
      </Routes>
);

const Wrapped = () => <Route path="/wrapped" element={<span>wrapped</span>} />
```

Is there a way of doing this kind of composition with the `Route` component with react-router v6? Or will react-router v6 only support `Route` directly nested in the `Routes` component?

Edit, more specifically I'm trying to get a recommendation for using a `ProtectedRoute` component, something among the lines of:

```
type Props  = {
  element: ReactElement;
  redirectRoute: string;
} & RouteProps;

const ProtectedRoute = ({element, redirectRoute, ...rest}: Props) => {
  const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth();
  <Route {...rest} element={isAuthenticated() ? element : <Navigate to={redirectRoute}/>}/>
}
```

EDIT:
It seems like this used to work in older beta versions, so this might be a bug. At the moment the latest version is 6.0.0-beta.4 &
I've logged an issue:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8066

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question itself. Also describe why you say *does not work* - does it throw an error, etc.

Comment: It will not render the route, I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to use Wrapped Component as a Router, but it's not. It's a React element returning a React Router element. Since you only need Router in this ***simple usecase***, you can treat is as a function:

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
   <Routes>
      {/* Use this as a normal function, and also function name etc.,*/}
      {Wrapped()}
      <Route path="/inline" element={<span>Inline works</span>} />
   </Routes>
</Suspense>
```

However, I would recommend not to complicate the routes by trying to add customizations on route and instead wrap your component that you want to route.

For eg.,

```
const Wrapped = () => <Route path="/wrapped" element={<span>wrapped</span>} />;
```

to

```
<Route path="/wrapped" element={<Wrapped>wrapped component</Wrapped>} />
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 'you are trying to use Wrapped Component as a Router`? What I'm trying to do is use composition to create an "enhanced" `Route` component. I just edited my question, maybe this will clarify it for you. Would you still use you're answer for the `ProtectedRoute` use case?

Answer (score 0):

> Or will react-router v6 only support Route directly nested in the Routes component?

Correct, RRv6 [does not support](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#route-doesnt-render-how-do-i-compose) route composition. Instead, try using your `<Wrapped />` component inside the `element` prop. E.g.

```
<Route path="/foo" element={<Wrapped>/* something here */</Wrapped>} />
```